Troubleshooting VRPN Client ROS with Motive and OptiTrack
I’m currently facing some issues while setting up the vrpn_client_ros package with Motive and OptiTrack cameras. Here’s a detailed breakdown of my setup and the issues I’m encountering:
Setup Details:
Ubuntu PC:

IP Address: 192.168.1.4
Connected to Windows PC via Ethernet (Right Port on Windows PC)
Running vrpn_client_ros package (ros noetic)

Windows PC (OptiTrack):

Right Port (to Ubuntu PC): 192.168.1.10
Left Port (connected to Ethernet switch for OptiTrack cameras): 192.168.1.6
Running Motive with VRPN Streaming Engine

Motive Settings:

Local Interface: 192.168.1.10
Multicast Interface: 192.168.1.4
VRPN Streaming Engine: Enabled
VRPN Broadcast Port: 3883

Issues:
Connection Establishment:

When running roslaunch vrpn_client_ros sample.launch server:=192.168.1.10, the connection is established, but no data is received.
Network Configuration:

Ping between devices:

Successful ping from Windows PC to Ubuntu PC (ping 192.168.1.4)
Successful ping from Ubuntu PC right port ping 192.168.1.10)
Unsuccessful ping from Ubuntu PC to Left Port on Windows PC (ping 192.168.1.6)
Device Visibility:

Nmap scan on Windows PC shows all 3 OptiTrack cameras:
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
Steps Taken to Resolve:
Check for VRPN Topics:

Verify if VRPN topics are being published : rostopic list

Check Data on VRPN Topics:
Check if data is being published on VRPN topics:

rostopic echo /vrpn_client_node/pose

Firewall on Windows PC:
Disabled the firewall to ensure it is not blocking the VRPN port (3883):
Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall > Turn Windows Defender Firewall on or off
Turn off for both private and public network settings.
Attempted to run NatNet Sample Client on Ubuntu:
> ./SampleClient 192.168.1.10 : 
> NatNet Sample Client (NatNet ver. 4.1.0.0)
> [NatNetLib]  [INFO]: [Client] Initializing using local address:
> 192.168.1.4
> [NatNetLib]  [INFO]: [Client] Initializing command listener.
> [NatNetLib] [ERROR]: Socket error 0: Success
> [NatNetLib] [ERROR]: [Client] Receive Buffer Size: 425984
> [NatNetLib]  [INFO]: [Client] Host information received. (HostApp:
> Motive  HostVer: 2.1.0.0  HostIP: 192.168.1.10 ()
> [NatNetLib]  [INFO]: [Client] Initializing data listener.
> [NatNetLib]  [WARN]: [HELPER] ReceiveBuffer size = 425984
> [NatNetLib]  [INFO]: [Client] Connected.
> [SampleClient] Server application info: Application: Motive (ver.
> 2.1.0.0) NatNet Version: 3.1.0.0 Client IP: Server IP:192.168.1.10 Server Name: Mocap Framerate : 35.00 Client initialized and ready.
> [SampleClient] Requesting Data Descriptions... [SampleClient] Received
> 6 Data Descriptions: Data Description # 0 (type=1) RigidBody Name :
> chessboardrb RigidBody ID : 5 RigidBody Parent ID : -1 Parent Offset :
> 0.00,0.00,0.00    Marker #0:      Position: 0.11, -0.14, -0.00    Marker #1:      Position: -0.06, -0.09, 0.06    Marker #2:      Position: 0.03, 0.12,
> -0.05     Marker #3:      Position: -0.08, 0.12, -0.00 Data Description # 1 (type=0) MarkerSet Name : chessboardrb Marker1 Marker2 Marker3 Marker4
> Data Description # 2 (type=0) MarkerSet Name : all chessboardrb_1
> chessboardrb_2 chessboardrb_3 chessboardrb_4 Data Description # 3
> (type=5) Camera Name : Prime 13W #74981 Camera Position (0.08, -0.05,
> 0.58) Camera Orientation (-0.00, 0.00, -0.00, 1.00) Data Description # 4 (type=5) Camera Name : Prime 13W #74980 Camera Position (-0.07,
> -0.05, 0.54) Camera Orientation (-0.06, 0.06, 0.02, 1.00) Data Description # 5 (type=5) Camera Name : Prime 13W #74982 Camera
> Position (0.19, -0.04, 0.61) Camera Orientation (0.03, 0.03, -0.00,
> 1.00)
> [SampleClient] Client is connected to server and listening for data..
> [SampleClient] Requesting Data Descriptions...

Current Status:

VRPN connection is maybe established but no data is received.
Facing difficulty in pinging from Ubuntu to the Left Port of the Windows PC.
Successfully seeing all 3 OptiTrack cameras via nmap on the Windows PC.
No traffic observed on port 3883 for the Right Port using Wireshark. Comes blank when filtered.

Looking for any suggestions or advice to resolve these issues.
Any help or insights from the community would be greatly helpful. Thanks so much in advance!
